# Spring JDBC and Oracle Db driver Connection

Tags: java, sql, oracle, spring

I am new to spring framework and trying my best to understand.
I am using Spring NamedParameterJDBC template for my operations

I am having this code in DAO

```
SqlParameterSource paramSource = new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(
            positionDO);
KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
return this.jdbcTemplate.update(sql, paramSource, keyHolder);
```

The problem is when I execute, I am getting this error

```
 org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL 
[INSERT INTO POSITION_TABLE VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; SQL state [null]; 
error code [0]; 
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection.prepareStatement(Ljava/lang/String;I)
Ljava/sql/PreparedStatement;
```

I googled and found that this is problem with old Ojdbc drivers like ojdbc14 which don't send auto generated keys.
Now I am unable to find what to do to load latest ojdbc driver by Spring OR any other way to do the same operation.

I am assuming spring-jdbc will be having default ojdbc driver. Am i correct? Because i didn't add any other drivers to my project.

--> Without Auto generate key, the whole process is working fine.

Comment: How are your project dependecies managed? Is it an ant project, a Maven project, an Eclipse project?

Comment: maven. and in pom.xml i can't see any driver dependency, however it's connection to db. wonder Spring has some inbuilt drivers or missing anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely your Java and ojdbc versions don't match. Since JDBC is part of JavaSE your JavaSE version and ojdbc version have to match.

ojdbc14 → Java 1.4

ojdbc5 → Java 1.5

ojdbc6 → Java 1.6

If your ojdbc driver is newer than your JavaSE versions then things should still work. You can get the Oracle JDBC driver from the 
[Oracle Download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html). Unfortunately you won't find them in Maven central so you'll need to manually deploy them to you Maven repository.

If you want to search for your ojdbc driver dependency use

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

If it's not there and not packaged with your artifact (WAR or EAR) then it's likely coming from your application server or similar.